# Capture / Monitor system data of application server in Graphite

Tags: memory, monitor, metrics, graphite, statsd

I am using graphite server to capture my metrics data and bring down to graphs. I have 4 application servers which is load balancer setup. My aim is capture system data such as cpu usage, memory usage, disk load, etc.,  for  all the 4 application servers. I setup an graphite environment in a separate server and i wanted to push the system data for all the applications servers to graphite and get it display as graphs. I don't know what needs to be done for feeding system data to graphite. My thinking was to install statsd in all application servers and feed the system data to graphite but looks like statsd does not support system data rather application data.

Can anyone help me to catch the right track. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Running [collectd](http://collectd.org) with a [graphite agent](https://github.com/indygreg/collectd-carbon) would be an excellent start to gather the information your after.

There is an almost unlimited amount of ways to get your data into graphite.

You can find a list of tools that have known to work very well with graphite on the readthedocs.org page: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/tools.html

There is also an example script that gathers load average from the system in the carbon project: [example-client.py](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/examples/example-client.py)